# How to Drag Image on Canvas with Meta All-in-One SDK

Tags: drag-and-drop, virtual-reality

I'm trying to drag an image on the Canvas with virtual reality toolkit like drag an image with mouse cursor in desktop. But I could not find the way to make image follow the meta cursor. Can you help me to make 2D image follow ometa cursor, so make image be dragged?

I need to know the way to make my program which people use Meta Quest 3 and play it in virtual reality mode.